# Unable to Activate Conda Environment in Emacs Shell

Tags: python, shell, pip, emacs, conda

After upgrading the MacOS to Mojave, I have noticed that I am no longer able to activate conda environments within Emacs shells. In regular MacOS terminal, the activation still works.

When a shell is created in Emacs, I get the following error:

```
/Users/user/miniconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenv
wrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')                 
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Users/user/miniconda3/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

If I try to do something with Pip, I get this:

```
File "/Users/user/miniconda3/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line
    8, in <module>                                                                                 
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion
    .py", line 9, in <module>                                                                       
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py
    ", line 7, in <module>                                                                          
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py"
    , line 22, in <module>                                                                          
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.
    py", line 9, in <module>                                                                        
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py",
    line 14, in <module>                                                                           
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", li
    ne 29, in <module>                                                                              
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version, site_packages, user_site
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__
    .py", line 9, in <module>                                                                       
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
    File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_sysconf
    ig.py", line 8, in <module>                                                                     
    from pip._internal.exceptions import InvalidSchemeCombination, UserInstallationInvalid
    ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions' (/User
    s/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py)
```

Any help on how to fix this is appreciated. Everything worked before the upgrade. Emacs configuration has not changed.

Comment: The example with pip, was that in the base environment?

Comment: @AMC It is hard to say. I belive it was out of an environment. I have discovered that things work when I add `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` to `.bashrc`. That is, somehow conda was not hooking into the shell. This seems hacky, but I am unsure of a thorough fix.

Comment: Maybe something is broken in the base environment? Are there any packages installed in there other than the defaults?